# Dynamically set itemValue of selectOneMenu in BootsFaces not working

Tags: jsf, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one, selectonemenu, bootsfaces

I am Developing such application in which there is Hibernate **Many to One Relationship** between Employee and Designation. While Inserting New Employee, I am Creating **Dynamic Options(which comes from Designation Table present in Database) of Select Menu for Designation**. I can Create options as follow in xhtml:

```
 <b:selectOneMenu value = "#{loginBean.designationVo}"> 
     <f:selectItems value = "#{loginController.designationListByInsert()}" var = "field" itemLabel = "#{field.designation}" itemValue = "#{field.designationId}"/>
    </b:selectOneMenu>
```

In Above Code, **designationListByInsert() method** will return List of Designation, Now I want to set **DesignationName as itemLabel** so user can see only Name of Designation along with it I want **DesignationId as itemValue**, but I can't set itemValue as shown in above code. It takes index value of List as itemValue. If I set DesignationId as itemLabel the it shows correct value but at same time If I Assign it to itemValue then it doesn't work. I can't understand what's wrong in my code. Please Someone help me to make it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will surely work.

Replace

> itemValue = "#{field.designationId}"

by

> itemValue = "#{field}"